# call a proc in the context of the surrounding block

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have an array of Procs, and I want to call all of them in the context of the enclosing block, and return the last value. Specifically:

```
require 'sinatra/base'

class App < Sinatra::Base
end

procs = [ proc{ status 200 }, proc{ 'Success!' } ]
App.send('get', '/') do
  procs.map(&:call).last
end

App.run!
```

It errors with `No method 'status'`. I expected it to behave like:

```
class App < Sinatra::Base
  get '/' do
    status 200
    'Success!'
  end
end
```

Any idea how I might do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `instance_eval` to change the binding of the procs:

```
App.send('get', '/') do
  procs.map{|p| instance_eval(&p) }.last
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting procs outside the scope of App, which is where the status method is defined. So you're not getting the binding you expect. Move the definition into the class and switching to lambdas works for me. Lambdas are true closures, so this makes sense.

Consider

```
  class App < Sinatra::Base
    procs = [ -> { status 200 }, -> { 'Success!' } ]

    get '/' do
      procs.map(&:call).last
    end
  end
```